# Can you have an Internal TestFlight build configure aps-environment for development?

Tags: ios, xcode

So maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but TestFlight builds you upload for Internal or External testing to the App Store are considered Ad Hoc distribution builds so will these be automatically set aps-environment to production? I don't see a way to create a distribution as development.